# Examples of useful applications that are being developed using open data

Tags: data-request, analysis

I am looking for news articles, tweets, or firms that everyone is talking about who are using open data. But, I have failed to find any useful application being developed that are using this open data thing.

Please name a few if you think open data is what people really get excited for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm so glad you bring up this question. Please take a look at the following links as well:

- http://www.opendata500.com/
- http://www.datainnovation.org/
- http://www.socrata.com/products/custom-web-and-mobile-apps-government-data/ (scroll down to 'Featured Apps')
- http://www.pinterest.com/socrata/open-data-applications/

Answer (score 9):

A great article from telegraph about [Meet the UK start-ups changing the world with open data](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/10930868/Meet-the-UK-start-ups-changing-the-world-with-open-data.html)

Also, if you check the [Data gov site of UK](http://data.gov.uk/apps), you will find 338 applications that use Open Data only in UK.

Actually, there are many apps out there and recently many start ups based on OD. Trying Google "Application + Open Data" will return a lot of case studies.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some additional resources for application examples:

- Code for America Commons: http://commons.codeforamerica.org/
- Code for America Library: http://codeforamerica.org/library
- Beyond Transparency: http://beyondtransparency.org/
- Technical.ly Directory: http://technical.ly/directory/
- Open 311 Applications: http://wiki.open311.org/GeoReport_v2/Support
- Chicago Applications by Open City Apps & DataMade: http://opencityapps.org/ & http://datamade.us/
- Governments on GitHub: http://government.github.com/

Answer (score 8):

You might also be interested in a roundup we did at Sunlight Foundation, which goes beyond apps: http://www.scribd.com/doc/219477511/The-Impacts-of-Open-Data

Answer (score 5):

Open Knowledge Foundation

Here i stye link to OKF German Projects site:
http://okfn.de/projects/

You will find many more projects searching the site.

Answer (score 4):

here a recent app (iOS and Android) we just released

http://www.visit04.com/

This application was created as part of a European program, the Degust’Alp program, which combines the territory of the Alpes de Haute Provence and the Province of Cuneo in Italy.

The app allows to discover the Alpes-de-Haute-Provence South of France area.

It's a free app which get all of its data from open data to display and discover natural, heritage, and tourist attractions, as well as events and resources available.

All Events: Locate the events, concerts, markets, flea markets, etc.. and coming close to your situation, discover its description, location and access conditions.

Of all public activities: learn sports, bright waters, hiking, skiing, mountain biking, nature … and free access offered by clubs and associations and how to participate.

And remarkable natural sites: sites and visits not miss around themes Nature, Culture and Heritage, Lifestyle and also locate the tourist.

Without open data and Open Street Map, this app would have not been possible.